# How do I get precise big number arithmetic results in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

(This might be a stupid question, but ...)

In Common Lisp, I can do something like

```
CL-USER> (expt 2 63)
9223372036854775808
```

I tried a few alternatives for Clojure:

```
user> (Math/pow 2 63)
9.223372036854776E18
```

Obviously, coercing to `int` didn't work:

```
user> (int (Math/pow 2 63))
IllegalArgumentException Value out of range for int: 9.223372036854776E18  clojure.lang.RT.intCast (RT.java:1211)
```

So I tried coercing to `bigint`:

```
user> (bigint (Math/pow 2 63))
9223372036854776000N
```

... but that didn't work either.

What's the recommended way to get the same result as above? (thanks!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow%28int%29) from `BigDecimal`:

```
user=> (.pow (bigdec 2) 63)
9223372036854775808M
```

As for dealing with bigdec/bigint Clojure there are the "auto promoting" computation functions with a trailing `'` (e.g. `*'`).  For other operations Java interop is always an option or third party libraries like https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower

Comment: Thanks! So is `bigdec` more idiomatic than `bigint`? (intuitively I would have expected the latter, since it's in the `clojure.lang` namespace)

Comment: you get an `clojure.lang/BigInt` with `bigint` - but a `java.math/BigDecimal` for `bigdec`. You might find one or the other more convenient, depending on your exposure to the JDK. For a BigInteger (what the JDK has for that) it is already a tad more clumsy: `(.pow (java.math.BigInteger. "2") 63)`

Answer (score 4):

Clojure uses Java math (double precision) as you have done for most things. If you wish to use arbitrary-precision math, you can write your own simple function using the BigDecimal class:

```
(defn my-pow [x y]
  (apply * (repeat y (bigdec x))))

(println (my-pow 2 63))

> lein run
(my-pow 2 63) => 9223372036854775808M
```